# Custom /etc/init.d/puma script - What is being executed when invoked with start/stop/...?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, services, sysvinit

Was trying to build my own custom `/etc/init.d/puma` script for handling puma processes, but cannot get any of my actual script to be executed when any of the normal keywords are used:

```
sudo service puma start
sudo service puma stop
sudo service puma restart
```

What exactly is being executed when any of these is invoked, and where does it come from? 
Can I somehow override it?

There's no other puma script anywhere on my system I could find (normally it would either be here in `/etc/init.d/` or directly in `/etc/` according to what I read.

```
# $1 is the second argument, e.g. start, stop, random_string   
case "$1" in 
  start)
    echo "'sudo service puma start' - Will never print this!"
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "'sudo service puma stop' - Will never print this!"
    ;;
  restart)
    echo "'sudo service puma restart' - Will never print this!"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "'sudo service puma anything_else_than_above' - Will always print!"
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}" 
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Did you give the name of the service to the `service` command?

Comment: Sorry @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, flew over me. I had and have been using 'sudo service puma x', error corrected. Thanks!